# How can I customize the code generation of InitializeComponent? More specifically, how can I post-process all of the generated code?

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, designer, initializecomponent

I'm trying to customize the Windows Forms Designer's code generation for `InitializeComponent`. The MSDN article ["Customizing Code Generation in the .NET Framework Visual Designers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx) contains a section ["Controlling Code Generation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx#custcodegen_topic8) that explains the basics of how this can be done.

I've closely followed an example in the above article:

```
//using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;

class SomeFormSerializer : CodeDomSerializer
{
    public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager,
                                     object value)
    {
        // first, let the default serializer do its work:
        var baseSerializer = (CodeDomSerializer)manager.GetSerializer(
                             typeof(Form).BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer));
        object codeObject = baseSerializer.Serialize(manager, value);

        // then, modify the generated CodeDOM -- add a comment as the 1st line:
        if (codeObject is CodeStatementCollection)
        {
            var statements = (CodeStatementCollection)codeObject;
            statements.Insert(0, new CodeCommentStatement("CODEDOM WAS HERE"));
        }

        // finally, return the modified CodeDOM:
        return codeObject;
    }
}
```

Now I hook this up to my form `SomeForm`:

```
[DesignerSerializer(typeof(SomeFormSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]
class SomeForm : Form { … }
```

The Forms Designer might then generate the following `InitializeComponent` code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    … /* (general setup code, such as a call to `this.SuspendLayout`) */ 

    // 
    // someButton
    // 
    … /* (someButton's properties are set) */

    // CODEDOM WAS HERE!
    // 
    // SomeForm
    // 
    … /* (form's properties are set) */

    … /* (general setup code, such as a call to `this.ResumeLayout`) */ 
}
```

Note that the comment `// CODEDOM WAS HERE` was not added as the very first line in `InitializeComponent`, but only as the first line of the code block that deals with the properties of the form object itself.

What would I have to do if I wanted to be able to modify the generated CodeDOM of the whole method, and not just of the part that deals with a specific object?

> **Background: Why do I want to do this?** In Windows Forms, if one wants flexible value conversion during data binding, one usually has to resort to subscribing to the `Format` and `Parse` events of some particular `Binding` object. So I'm creating a specialized `Binding` subclass (let's call it `ConvertingBinding`) that simplifies this process a bit.
>
> Now, the issue is that when data bindings are set up in the Windows Forms Designer, the generated code creates instances of `Binding`; however, I would want the designer to instantiate my specialized subclass instead. My current approach is to let the designer create a CodeDOM tree first, then walk that tree and replace all instantiations of `Binding` by instantiations of `ConvertingBinding`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create two `Form` class. First `Form` with a `DesignerSerializerAttribute`. Second `Form` is descendant from first. After that you can customize `InitializeComponent()` for second `Form` and it's controls or components.
For this you should use `manager.Context` to get all `StatementContext` and  `CodeStatementCollection` objects that contains serialized code of `Form`'s controls.

Here is some simple steps.
Include libraries:

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
```

Create new form and add `DesignerSerializerAttribute`:

```
[DesignerSerializer(typeof(CustomFormSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]
class CustomForm : Form { … }
```

Create `CustomForm` descendant and add some controls or components to it:

```
class CustomForm1 : CustomForm { … }
```

Add method to `CustomFormSerializer` for processing `CodeStatementCollection`, for example:

```
private void DoSomethingWith(CodeStatementCollection statements)
{
    statements.Insert(0, new CodeCommentStatement("CODEDOM WAS HERE"));
}
```

In `Serialize` method use cycle through `manager.Context`:

```
public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager,
    object value)
{
    //Cycle through manager.Context            
    for (int iIndex = 0; manager.Context[iIndex] != null; iIndex++)
    {
        object context = manager.Context[iIndex];

        if (context is StatementContext)
        // Get CodeStatementCollection objects from StatementContext
        {
            ObjectStatementCollection objectStatementCollection =
                ((StatementContext)context).StatementCollection;

            // Get each entry in collection.
            foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in objectStatementCollection)
                // dictionaryEntry.Key is control or component contained in CustomForm descendant class
                // dictionartEntry.Value is CodeDOM for this control or component
                if (dictionaryEntry.Value is CodeStatementCollection)
                    DoSomethingWith((CodeStatementCollection)dictionaryEntry.Value);
        }

        //Do something with each collection in manager.Context:
        if (context is CodeStatementCollection)
            DoSomethingWith((CodeStatementCollection)context);
    }

    // Let the default serializer do its work:
    CodeDomSerializer baseClassSerializer = (CodeDomSerializer)manager.
        GetSerializer(value.GetType().BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer));
    object codeObject = baseClassSerializer.Serialize(manager, value);

    // Then, modify the generated CodeDOM:
    if (codeObject is CodeStatementCollection)
        DoSomethingWith((CodeStatementCollection)codeObject);

    // Finally, return the modified CodeDOM:
    return codeObject;
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. This seems sufficient to replace `Binding` instances; but I still cannot access the whole method, i.e. the first few lines and last few lines in `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: @stakx: The first few lines in `InitializeComponent` are always consist of `CodeVariableDeclarationStatement` objects. If you make changes to any of these objects in `CodeStatementCollection` or add new `CodeVariableDeclarationStatement` to the collection, all of these changes will appear in the first few lines. Any other `CodeStatement` lines will appear after all `CodeVariableDeclarationStatement` lines.